# How to count and order by max by other table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm having two table:

```
CREATE TABLE `apps` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `downloads_stats` (
    `app_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    `date` DATE NOT NULL,
    `downloads` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`app_id`, `date`),
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
```

First is the list of my apps, the other stores the download number of each app. What is the best way to get 10 most downloaded apps ? I can do simple `JOIN` and then `SUM` and `ORDER BY` but is it the most efficient way?

Comment: Yes it is, unless you don't need the app name, then just select against the download_stats table.

Comment: Maybe something like that? But then you lost order ofc: 
   select name from apps where id in (select app_id from downloads_stats order by downloads desc limit 10);

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I'd use `LEFT JOIN` with `GROUP BY`, e.g.:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, SUM(ds.downloads) AS 'downloads'
FROM apps a LEFT JOIN downloads_stats ds ON a.id = ds.app_id
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
ORDER BY SUM(ds.downloads) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

If you just want the `app_id` then `JOIN` is not needed, e.g.:

```
SELECT app_id, SUM(downloads) as 'downloaded'
FROM downloads_stats
GROUP BY app_id
ORDER BY SUM(downloads) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , you can use `LEFT JOIN` with `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT  a.id , a.name , SUM(ds.downloads) AS 'downloads'
FROM   apps  a   LEFT  JOIN   downloads_stats ds ON a.id = ds.app_id
GROUP BY   a.id ,  a.name
ORDER BY   downloads DESC
LIMIT 10;
```